# “create view” and "Other query" merge problem in Codeigniter using mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

In phpmyadmin i run both query is working and i get my value but when i want to execute this query in codeigniter i faced problem how to execute both query using same function.In the below are my query.

Query:

```
create view V_average_marks AS
 select student_id,avg(total_mark) as average_mark from total_marks 
 group by student_id;

SELECT student_id,(average_mark), FIND_IN_SET( average_mark, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( average_mark
ORDER BY average_mark DESC ) 
FROM V_average_marks )
) AS rank
FROM V_average_marks;
```

I get my value when i run this on phpmyadmin but i confused when i run in codeigniter.Can't find the correct way.

Model:

```
public function final_rank()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT student_id,(average_mark), FIND_IN_SET(average_mark,(GROUP_CONCAT( average_mark ORDER BY average_mark DESC)FROM V_average_marks)) AS rank FROM V_average_marks";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing with the return value from final_rank()?

Comment: i want to rank them according their numbers.

Comment: Ok,  I should have asked,  what result do you get from calling the final_rank() function. Can you show the result?

Comment: Those are not the same queries: `(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(` vs `(GROUP_CONCAT(`

Comment: when i tired in codeigniter in model it show nothing...it  show error 500 but when i reun it on sql it give me my value with rank..
student_id  average_mark  rank
110          450.6667               1
111          329.3333               2
112          285.0000               3
113          77.3333                10
114         70.0000                  11
etc these are the data when i run it on sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found correct answer:

```
create view V_average_marks AS
select student_id,avg(total_mark) as average_mark from total_marks 
group by student_id; 

create view V_rank AS
SELECT student_id,(average_mark), FIND_IN_SET( average_mark, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( average_mark
ORDER BY average_mark DESC ) 
FROM V_average_marks )
) AS rank
FROM V_average_marks;

SELECT * from V_rank;
```

From model call `SELECT * from V_rank` this sql and you can get desire result